# Javascript won't load over network using MAMP?

Tags: javascript, testing, localhost, local, mamp

I'm using MAMP for a local website, I have www.mywebsite.dev set up and everything works fine.

But when I try to access by 192.168.0.198 - my comp's IP, it will load the website fine, images, css and all. But it fails to load the javascript. I've checked the paths and all look fine - why would it load everything but JS??

(I need to use the IP to test over the network)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you see in Fiddler or Firebug?

Comment: Or ctrl-i or j in chrome and check out the network and refresh the page. do you get any error codes?

Comment: This is weird, I've traced it down to a statement which doesn't work over the network for some reason. ----> function moveTriangle(target) { var pos = target.position().left + target.width()/2 - 15; }

Comment: What I don't get is it's a helper function, and determines the value based on the argument send to it. Why would this piece of code throw an error?

Comment: Check jQuery versions, try clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the help, I managed to get it working by clearing the cache in my CMS's navigation section. Turned out one of the elements were not loading in quick enough. Cheers!